# Insert record into data table using Liquid in PowerApps?

Tags: database, liquid, powerapps, powerapps-canvas, powerapps-portal

Is there a way to insert a record into a Dataverse table by using Liquid in a PowerApps portal application? I checked Googled, but no specific info on it.

Comment: correct me if i'm wrong, but liquid is a templating language, so it's only for fetching and filtering data

Comment: I can't really correct you, but I can agree with you that it seems like it is. I searched the web on how to insert records, could not find anything related to that.